# Selecting text with Sublime Text 2

Tags: selection, text-editor

I have been using an evaluation copy of Sublime Text 2. Quite recently, I have noticed that I have been unable to drag and select text with my mouse (with the text being highlighted as I select it), or even click in a different part of the document to change the position of the cursor.

I am now reduced to using the humble arrow keys on my keyboard to move around the document.

Is this a normal feature of Sublime Text 2? I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the programme, and still no change. Or do I have to upgrade to a full licenced copy (which I have been planning to do.)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Kind Regards,

Robert

London,
United Kingdom

Comment: check this out https://github.com/colinta/SublimeMoveText

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue earlier today. The solution is to remove the Sublime Text app data folder.

On my Windows 8 machine the folder was located at:
C:\Users[user_name]\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2

Hope this helps!

Best,

Mike